# In .aspx, how to pass a value from asp:Repeater to code behind function

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, repeater

So, I want to use jquery to set the text of a button, depending on the value of a property in the current row of a repeater.

I need to call a function in the code-behind to map the value to the text the button should have. So, I need to pass to my foo function, the string value of the UserStatus property for the current item in the repeater.

I want to do the following, although this syntax is obviously not correct:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="dgCustomer" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate> 
    <input id="rb" name="rb" type="radio" onclick='javascript:$("input.magicbutton").val("<%= foo(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserStatus")) %>");'
```

If the codebehind contains the following method definition:

```
protected string foo(string status)
```

What is the correct syntax to call foo with an Item value from the repeater?

Comment: This is a good answer for "How to call c# function from aspx".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the <%= with <%# and it looks like you should be good to go.

Comment: <%# is for expressions to be evaluated while you are databinding. <%= is pretty much equivalent to Response.Write and can be used almost anywhere outside of databinding contexts.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I see with that code snippet is that you need to use a databinding nugget (`<%# ... %>`) instead of the expression nugget (`<%= ... %>`).

You may run into issues with surrounding your nugget with double quotes, since it contains double quotes already.  You may have to have `foo` return the value in quotes, or even have have `foo` just return the whole `onclick` event...